# Can’t use cloudflare with iphub.info

Tags: php, cloudflare

I tried to block vpns and proxies to my website using iphub.info, but cloudflare ip’s get also blocked, so basicly no one can access my website!
Is there a way to whitelist cloudflare for https://iphub.info? I created the website with php.
Thanks in advance!
This is how iphub looks if an ip is bad:

```
<?php
namespace IPHub;

class Lookup {
    public static function isBadIP(string $ip, string $key, bool $strict = false) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($ch, [
            CURLOPT_URL => "http://v2.api.iphub.info/ip/{$ip}",
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => ["X-Key: {$key}"]
        ]);
        try {
            $block = json_decode(curl_exec($ch))->block;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            throw $e;
        }
        if ($block) {
            if ($strict) {
                return true;
            } elseif (!$strict && $block === 1) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cloudflare provides a list of ip's they may use to access your site:
https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/

You could use the files provided: https://www.cloudflare.com/ips-v4 and https://www.cloudflare.com/ips-v6 to check if it is a bad ip.

You could fetch the ips using `file_get_contents` but you should cache the results to prevent sending a request to cloudflare for every request.